# Operate QL 500 P-Touch label Printer in C# Application

Tags: c#, .net, printing, label

I am making a POS system in windows forms using C#. Project is complete except one thing. I have to print the each sale on a QL 500 P-Touch label Printer. But I don't really know how to operate it from a application. I am new to such a label printing. I have googled but didn't find the satisfactory tutorial or documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download the [b-PAC SDK](http://www.brother.com/product/dev/label/bpac/index.htm).

Example C# projects are included; it's actually quite easy.

```
bpac.DocumentClass doc = new DocumentClass();
if (doc.Open("templateFile.lbx"))
{
    doc.GetObject("field1").Text = "...";
    doc.GetObject("field2").Text = "...";

    doc.StartPrint("", PrintOptionConstants.bpoDefault);
    doc.PrintOut(1, PrintOptionConstants.bpoDefault);
    doc.EndPrint();
    doc.Close();
}
```

Comment: Thanks... Tutorial is useful. You are great brother.

Comment: Im newbee at c# too It gives an error interop type 'bpac.DocumentClass' can not be embedded. Use the applicable interface instead ? What should I do ?

Comment: @albatross: Not sure. Does the bitness of your application match the SDK's? If I'm remembering correctly, the SDK only has 32-bit DLLs.

Comment: I directly downloaded Visual Studio Express 2012 for Windows 8 and there is no information whether it is 64 or 32-bit ? How can I check. Moreover it can see all the methods like getObject or Print out Is it normal to have such a problem ? Thanks

Comment: You have to set your *project* to [run 32-bit](http://davidstechtips.com/2010/06/force-net-application-to-run-in-32-bit-process-on-64-bit-windows/).

Comment: @josh3736  bpac 3.0+ supports 64-bit.

Comment: How can I set width of the label. Is it possible to change size of the bar caode label using API?

Comment: `doc.SetPrinter(..., fitPage)` lets you specify whether the template should be fit to the label width.

Answer (score 0):

I had to manually edit the project.csproj file to make the proper reference.

```
<ItemGroup>
    <COMReference Include="bpac">
      <Guid>{90359D74-B7D9-467F-B938-3883F4CAB582}</Guid>
      <VersionMajor>1</VersionMajor>
      <VersionMinor>0</VersionMinor>
      <Lcid>0</Lcid>
      <WrapperTool>tlbimp</WrapperTool>
      <Isolated>False</Isolated>
    </COMReference>
  </ItemGroup>
```